# 「ある」と「ない」は動詞か形容詞か…

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

「ある」と「ない」はどんな品詞名か教えてください。​​​​​

Answer (score 6):

「～がある」という時の「ある」は、普通の**動詞**です。ところが、これを否定して「～がない」という時、この「ない」は**形容詞**です。

本来、動詞の否定は「書かない」「見ない」「来ない」のように、動詞の後ろに自立しない**助動詞**である「ない」をくっつけて作るものなので、「ある」の否定は「× あらない」となるはずなのですが、この形は標準日本語にはありません。日本語では、「× あらない」の意味を表すのに形容詞の「ない」を借りてきて使います。

これは**補充形** ([suppletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion)) といい、英語が "go" の過去形に "*go-ed" などではなく、もともと "wend" の過去形だった "went" を借りて使っているのと同じです。

---

ちなみに、「書かない」の「ない<sub>1</sub>」と「～がない」の「ない<sub>2</sub>」が同じ形なのは偶然で、本当は別の単語です。西日本の方言では「書かへん」とか「書かん」のように全く別の形になります。「書かない」も「ない<sub>2</sub>」とほとんど同じ活用をしますが、少し違いがあるので今のところ形容詞ではなく**動詞の否定形**（動詞 + ほぼ形容詞変化の助動詞）とされています。しかし東京の言葉ではどんどん使い方が形容詞に近づいている（書きませんでした→書かなかったです）ので、将来は形容詞になる日が来るかもしれません。

Answer (score 4):

「お金がある。」というときの「ある」は、動詞です。([辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/7643/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B/))
(「置いてある」「吾輩は猫である」というときの「ある」は、補助動詞です。
「昔々あるところに・・・」というときの「ある」は、連体詞です。)
「お金がない。」「おもしろくない。」というときの「ない」は、形容詞です。([辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162263/meaning/m0u/))
「食べない」というときの「ない」は、助動詞です。([辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162271/meaning/m0u/))

Answer (score 2):

ある is a verb and an adnominal adjective.

ない is adjective and verbal auxiliary. 
ない as adjective means " non-existent" like テレビがない. ない as verbal auxiliary is set at the end of 未然形 of a verb and means "negative" like たべない.