# How to make this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

I have to use the grammar ようによっては in the following sentence. The meaning in English is

> Depending on how you treat me, I can be a gentleman or not.

My attempt is as follows, but I think it is partially incorrect.

> 僕は、君が扱いようによっては、優しくなるかどうか

How to fix it?

Comment: See if [How does the use of いかんによっては in this question determine one answer over another?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7035/78) points to what's incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 扱いよう ("way to treat") is a noun, so its "subject" cannot be marked with が. Unfortunately, Xの扱いよう would mean either "how to treat X" or "how X treats", depending on the context. Usually `object + の扱いよう` means "how to treat it" (e.g., ハサミの扱いよう "how to use scissors") and `person + の扱いよう` tends to mean "how (person) treats" (e.g., 私の扱いようが悪かった "I used it badly"). In the following example, I added another modifier, ～に対する, which is less ambiguous, so that the 君の part will be interpreted in one way.
- The sentence lacks the final predicate (verb, adjective, or copula), because 優しくなるかどうか ("*whether* I will be kind or not") is a noun phrase.

You can say like these (sorry, only the first one uses ようによっては strictly):

> - 君の私に対する扱いようによっては、私は優しくもなるし、ならないこともある。
> - 君の私に対する扱いようによって、私が優しくなるかどうかが決まる。
> - 私が優しくなるかどうかは、君が私をどう扱うか[次第【しだい】だ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30918/5010)。