# How is writing with 旧字体 over 新字体, using lots of 表外漢字 and using 漢字 in place of かな in a word that is almost always written with かな perceived?

Tags: kanji, orthography, kanji-choice, kana-usage, jōyō-kanji

Examples:

> A: 毎日、学校で桜の木を見る。（新字体）
> B: 毎日、學校で櫻の木を見る。（旧字体）

> A: この国の歴史を研究しています。（新字体）
> B: この國の歷史を硏究しています。（旧字体）

> A: 私はワニがすきです。（カタカナ）
> B: 私は鰐が好きです。（表外漢字）

> A: 私の好きな魚はハタハタとスズキです。（カタカナ）
> B: 私の好きな魚は鰰と鱸です。（表外漢字）

> A: このページを見てください。（一つの漢字）
> B: 此の頁を見て下さい。（四つの漢字）

What is the general perception of writing in the way the B examples are over the A examples? Is it considered a good thing or a bad thing to most people?

I also asked this question on HiNative, with the original question here: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/18102270

Comment: +1 for including your question posted elsewhere. It always helps to include as much information as possible, because it leads to a higher likelihood that you will get accurate answers.

Comment: For function words: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24068/7810

Answer (score 6):

Some 表外漢字 like 狼 and 嘘 are perfectly safe in ordinary writing. Some are simply too difficult. It largely depends on the character. Personally I can read 鰐 but not 鰰/鱸. See also [Why are the names of plants and animals often written in katakana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20840/5010)

旧字体 was the standard way of writing in the past, so it's natural if the text is related to periods before WWII. It still remains in some proper nouns. For example 櫻井 is not a rare family name. Otherwise, it's hard to describe the *general* perception, but it would be... "simply nonstandard" or "something weird is happening".

- Is this text a simulation or an excerpt of a prewar document?
- Is this person practicing 旧字体? Is this person trying to show off his knowledge of kanji?
- Maybe this person does not know how to write standard Japanese? Maybe is he/she from Taiwan?
- Maybe this person does not have very good eyesight, so he/she did not notice his IME accidentally converted hiragana into 旧字体?

As for 此の頁を見て下さい, I would probably think this was written by a very old person or a novelist who has a unique taste.

Comment: What's the most unusual part of 此の頁を見て下さい? The 此の, the 頁, or the 下さい? The kanji gairaigo is definitely weird, but as a nonnative speaker I find 下さい much more comfortable to read than ください: the simple kanji jumps out at me where a long string of kana would blend together and take a second or two to recognize. I always have difficulty understanding when little kids in manga speak all in hiragana, for example.